# How can I open a letter in mail.ru using selenium's webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I try:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://e.mail.ru/messages/inbox/')
...
letterTag = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.b-datalist__item__addr")
```

and it gives me:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"div.b-datalist__item__addr"}
```

I see *'div.b-datalist__item__addr'* in develop tools, but I can't find it in page's source code. I suppose it generates by javascript... I need to click this element in order to open a letter. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you properly logged in?

Comment: @MattClark, yes. At least, I think so. I've entered name and password, using send_keys() and submit().

Comment: Have u tried: `driver.execute_script("... ")` with suitable JS code?

Comment: @Würgspaß, no, I haven't. Unfortunately, I'm not good in JS. But I've found another solution according to selenium's documentation. As I supposed JS generates HTML and I have to wait. I used WebDriverWait().

Answer (score 0):

[Link to documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). 
My solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

name = input("Login: ")
password = input("Password: ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://mail.ru/')
driver.find_element_by_id('mailbox__login')
mail_name = driver.find_element_by_id('mailbox__login')
mail_name.send_keys(name)
mail_pass = driver.find_element_by_id('mailbox__password')
mail_pass.send_keys(password)
mail_pass.submit()
# get first letter
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.js-href.b-datalist__item__link")))
element.click()
```